# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::emails does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando usar o "sync" para alimentar uma tabela que relaciona email com o cadastro de uma pessoa.

Essa tabela que eu criei e pretendo alimentar contém o id do cadastro e o id do email.

Para alimenta-la, vou usar o "sync" e no modelo cadastro eu criei a função

```
public function Emails(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\emails','cadastro_emails','cadastro_id','email_id');
}
```

Para inserir no banco, eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
   $cadSa      = $cadastro::firstOrCreate($cad)->all();
   $cadSa->Emails()->sync([3,4]);
```

Essa função("Emails") aparentemente funciona pois, na hora de trazer os dados de email relacionado aos cadastros, a resposta é rápida e certa.

Então, o que está errado ao fazer a sincronização na tabela de intersecção através do "sync"?

Comment: Olá! Me parece que está faltando algumas linhas no seu código. Onde é chamado a propriedade title? Qual linha está acontecendo o erro? Você pode [edit] a pergunta incluindo esses detalhes.

Comment: eu resolvi o problema do emails...realmente eu estava chamando ele errado, porém, ainda não consegui solucionar a questão....vamos lá:
          $id = $cadastro::firstOrCreate($cad)->id;
          $cadastro->Emails()->sync([3,4]);

mas ele indica que o valor de "cadastro_id" está nulo, então, eu lancei o valor dele dessa forma 
         $cadastro_email->cadastro_id=$id;
ficando assim:
        $id = $cadastro::firstOrCreate($cad)->id;
        $cadastro_email->cadastro_id=$id;
        $cadastro->Emails()->sync([3,4]);

mesmo assim, ele ainda diz que o valor de cadastro_id está nulo...

Comment: Poste toda classe

Comment: segue o controller que faz isso:<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\cadastro;
use App\emails;
use App\telefones;
use App\cadastros_emails;

class cadastroCtrl extends Controller
{
   public function all(cadastro $cadastro){
       $all = $cadastro->all();
       return view('paginasCrm1.cadastros.home',compact('all'));
   } 


public function cadastra(Request $Request,cadastro $cadastro){           
          $cadastro::create($Request->all());  
          $cadastro->Emails()->sync(['1']);
}
}

Comment: e a classe cadastros(model)
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class cadastro extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['nome','cpf','rg','nascimento','cargo_id'];
    protected $table= "cadastros";

    public function Cargos(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\cargos','cargo_id');
    }

    public function Emails(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\emails','cadastros_emails','cadastros_id','emails_id');
    }

   }

Comment: `$cadSa = $cadastro::firstOrCreate($cad)` e depois `$cadSa->Emails()->sync([3,4]);` você está fazendo errado por isso dos problemas